# Read variable with more than two digits from string between chars c#

Tags: c#, string, list

I have multiple lines inside a list of strings and each line has this kind of structure just with different variables

```
line = "14*x1 + 2*x2 + 3*x3 >= 2";
```

I want the values 14 , 2 and 3 to be saved inside a different `List<int>`

The following code only works if the variable has one digit, so 14 would be saved as 4 only

```
List<double> list = new List<double>()
foreach (var line in functionlist)
{        
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {                    
        if (line[i].Equals('*'))
        {             
            list.Add(line[i-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the problem is `line[i-1]`, which only saves the digit before the '*' and substring needs to be used. I just dont know how.

Comment: Seems like a pretty straight forward regex.

Comment: You could have a temporary `string` that keeps concatenating until it hits a '*' and only starts when it hits a digit, then parse that into a double and ONLY THEN add it to the `List<double>`,
and repeat throughout the whole `string`

Comment: For what it's worth, parsing data like this is very typical of basic examples of using parsers (from lex & yacc to Antlr).  If you are looking for a more general solution, you might look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using regular expressions:

```
List<double> numbers = new Regex(@"(\d+)\*x").Matches(line)
                         .Cast<Match>()
                         .Select(m => double.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value))
                         .ToList();
```

EDIT: updated to parse the numbers.

Comment: If you're using the latest version of `System.Text.RegularExpressions` you don't need the `Cast<Match>` as `MatchCollection` already inherits `ICollection<Match>, IEnumerable<Match>, IEnumerable, IList<Match>, IReadOnlyCollection<Match>, IReadOnlyList<Match>, ICollection, IList`

Comment: @KevinSmith Are you using Core or something? Regex is just part of the System.dll assembly for me.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Can I ask how to edit the code to get the value behind the "=" aswell ?

Comment: @itsme86 no it's called nuget, it's the package manager for .net :-) This package works with all version of .net framework dropping back to .NET 4.5 -  https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.RegularExpressions/4.3.0

Comment: @M.Cal No problem. I'd get the number after the "=" in a different statement: `double answer = double.Parse(new Regex(@"=\W*(\d+)").Match(line).Groups[1].Value);`

Comment: @KevinSmith I'm just not sure asking OP to install a nuget package for functionality that already exists out of the box is worth getting rid of a `.Cast<>()` call.

Comment: Is it also possible to get the variables and the answer in the same list ?

Comment: @M.Cal `numbers.Add(answer);` You'd just have to know that the last number in the list is the answer I guess.

Comment: @itsme86 it comes by default with dotnet core, also nowhere in the question does it say what version of the framework they're using.

Comment: @itsme86 Thanks again, i made sure to credit you in a comment. I meant  to add the answer right after the variables for each equation, not adding every answer at the end of the list.

Comment: @M.Cal Isn't there only one answer? I only see one "=" character.

Comment: My bad, i forgot to say that the text file i am trying to parse has one equation per line, like 30 different ones. Right now I can Parse the first 3 variables from each line,  for every line, then add the answers at the end of the list, not being able to tell which answer belongs to which equation

Comment: @M.Cal You probably want a strong type then to keep track of stuff. Something like `class Equation { public List<double> Variables { get; } public double Answer { get; } }`. That way you can have a `List<Equation>` where each item in the list represents one line from your file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
  string line = "14*x1 + 2*x2 + 3*x3 = 2";
  var arr = line.Split('+');
  var result = arr.Select(x => x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf('*')));
```

Comment: This is just an example, what if they have different operators, like '-' or '/', instead of '+' ?
Bug good answer regardless

Answer (score 0):

Simple RegEx of `(\d+)\*` should do the trick.

```
var line = "14*x1 + 2*x2 + 3*x3 = 2";

var matches = Regex.Matches(line, @"(\d+)\*");

// [] { 14, 2 , 3 }
var numbers = matches.Select(x => double.Parse(x.Groups[1].Value)).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is just an example, what if they have different operators, like '-' or '/', instead of '+' ? Bug good answer regardless

Comment: Did you actually try this? You can't `.Select()` on `matches`.

Comment: @itsme86 Yep I tested this, actually wrote the test in xunit... no compile errors at all.

Comment: it doesn't compile in VS 15.7.5.

Comment: That's the version of VS I'm using... I'm using `System.Text.RegularExpressions` @ 4.2.1.0, I'm guessing you're using some old legacy version? 4.0.0.0? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.RegularExpressions/4.3.0